# How to insert an org-deadline from lisp with a warning period?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, deadline, timestamped

The [org documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html) tells us that we can use special syntax for a deadline to have a warning period:

> You can specify a different lead time for warnings for a specific
> deadlines using the following syntax. Here is an example with a
> warning period of 5 days ‘DEADLINE: <2004-02-29 Sun -5d>’. This
> warning is deactivated if the task gets scheduled and you set
> org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled to t.

This is also [supported by Orgzly](https://github.com/orgzly/orgzly-android/issues/636), where I want to use it.

I'd assume that I could call `org-deadline` with this syntax but it just throws out the warning period:

```
(org-deadline nil "<2021-07-20 Tue -1d>")
   ;; => DEADLINE: <2021-07-20 Tue>
```

The documentation of `org-deadline` says

> With two universal prefix arguments, prompt for a warning delay.

But this doesn't help me since I don't want to call interactively.

Since my entries get automatically updated by calendar sync I also have the requirement that the previous *DEADLINE:* entry has to get removed in this case, which is automatically handled by `org-deadline`.
I assume I could handle this with `org-remove-timestamp-with-keyword` but I'm not sure which function to use for timestamp insertion if `org-deadline` doesn't support the warning period syntax.

How do I insert a deadline from elisp with a warning period?

Comment: I think this is a bug: the function `org--deadline-or-schedule` saves a repeater (e.g `+2d` ) and adds it back at the end, but the regexp does not match a warning period (e.g. `-2d`) so it drops it. You should probably report it with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: Update: this was in fact just verified as a bug. See https://orgmode.org/list/87bl5dobfj.fsf@gmail.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per NickD's comment this may well be a bug. In the meantime, it looks like this does what you're aiming for (or at least points you in the right direction):

```
(defun dunne//add-deadline-warning (w)
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (let* ((regexp org-deadline-time-regexp))
      (if (not (re-search-forward regexp (line-end-position 2) t))
      (user-error "No deadline information to update")
    (let* ((rpl0 (match-string 1))
           (rpl (replace-regexp-in-string " -[0-9]+[hdwmy]" "" rpl0)))
      (replace-match
       (concat org-deadline-string
           " <" rpl
           (format " -%dd" w)
           ">") t t))))))

(defun dunne//add-deadline-with-warning (w)
  (org-deadline nil)
  (dunne//add-deadline-warning w))
```

I mined the contents of `dunne//add-deadline-warning` from the two-prefix case in `org--deadline-or-schedule` and ripped out the logic to handle existing deadlines / allow selecting a warning date.

Comment: Thank you, this works! If anyone is wondering: w is expected to be a (positive) decimal number.